# Will a copper plate spin near a motor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I'm revising old physics papers and I'm unable to answer the following question.

> If a horizontal copper plate is suspended at the centre by a thread, over a motor whose axis is aligned vertically, which of the following statements is true?
>
> 1. The disc will not rotate because copper is not magnetic.
> 2. The disc will rotate because copper is magnetic.
>
> ...

Wikipedia tells me copper is *diamagnetic* meaning it will produce a magnetic field in opposition to an externally applied magnetic field. I'm having a few conflicting thoughts.

- The opposing field will push against the components of the motor which produce the first field, so it will spin.
- Wait, neither field will produce a significant torque on the *copper*, because it's not that kind of magnetism, so it won't spin.
- Wait, the opposing field will retard the motor, so it must push back on *something*. Maybe the copper disc will be lifted?
- Wait, the magnetic field will be north on one side of the disc, south on the other, and this pattern will spin with the motor, applying torque.
- Wait, the field is symmetric so it won't.

Aargh! I think I'm overcomplifying things and the correct answer is 1., but I feel like I know less now than when I started. What's the real answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer.

Copper is weakly, (very weakly) diamagnetic, ie. it's less permeable to magnetic fields than free space, and so will be repelled but not to a significant and useful extent by a uniform and unvarying magnetic field within earth's gravity. I'd not expect it to levitate, as the force to levitate would be much less than it's mass under even the strongest static magnetic fields able to be made by present physics.

In electrically conducting materials, such as copper, any varying magnetic field will produce  a set of induced eddy currents, which in turn produce a magnetic field of their own, resulting in force in the opposite direction of magnetic rotation or the same direction depending on the frequency of the changing magnetic field, size of apparatus, and an hysteric effect. (delay in secondary induction)

There will be force on the disk to rotate, the actual force to rotate will be small as motors are designed to be efficient - ie. produce little variable magnetic field outside of their housing. Most threads are twisted and on tension will themselves produce torque and change length slightly, oscillating, perhaps try a single thread of Kevlar for less experimental interference derived from the materials.